# Can I shoot video with a Canon Rebel XT/350D?

Tags: canon, video

Hello I've been borrowing this camera from a friend because I'm on holiday and they're working. I think it's called a Canon Digital EOS Rebel XT.

Does it film video? I've gone through all the modes and it takes such nice pictures [image: picture of camera]

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben, can you edit the title of your question, to include the camera model? As it is, the title is not very descriptive. Thanks! =)

Comment: @PhilipKendall I've seen both done here from time to time. I figured the "pro" side of argument was kinda along the lines of "teach a man to fish...". But point taken, and in retrospect, I agree with you. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it film video?

**No.**

I used a Rebel XT/350D for a long time, and I can tell you that it does not record video. It was a great camera for learning, but it's about 11 years old at this point and has been far surpassed by its successors in the Rebel line.

The first Canon Rebel model to officially support video was the Rebel T1i/500D, and every model since then has had video.

Comment: Why does it have a video save mode then?

Comment: It doesn't. It does have a "Video system" setting that switches the video out port between NTSC and PAL formats. The video out port lets you display photos you've taken on a television. It has nothing to do with recording video.